# calling separate python program in unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

i am new to python and unit test.following is the main unittest program that calls other python programs which acts a test cases

```
import unittest
from test import test_support

class MyTestCase1(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_feature_one(self):

        print "testing feature one"
        execfile("/root/test/add.py")

def test_main():
    test_support.run_unittest(MyTestCase1);

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_main()
```

add.py is basic program that adds two no and displays it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def disp(r):
        print r
def add():
        res = 3+5;
        disp(res)
add()
```

but there is problem when i call a function from another function. i hit the following error when i try to run unit test(first program).But if i run add.py as single program outside the unit test suit it works fine. kindly need help in understanding this scenario

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_feature_one (__main__.MyTestCase1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "first.py", line 17, in test_feature_one
    execfile("/root/test/add.py")
  File "/root/test/add.py", line 12, in <module>
    add()
  File "/root/test/add.py", line 10, in add
    disp(res)
 NameError: global name 'disp' is not defined

 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From docs on execfile (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) :

"Remember that at module level, globals and locals are the same dictionary.
...
If the locals dictionary is omitted it defaults to the globals dictionary. If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is executed in the environment where execfile() is called."

I'm not very familiar to how exactly globals and locals works here, so I won't be able to give deep explanation, but from what I understood:
the key here is that you're running execfile from function. If you run it from module level, it will work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    execfile('blah')
```

But if you run it from function:

```
def f():
    execfile('blah')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

it will fail. Because of magic with globals and locals.

How to fix your example: add dictionary to arguments of execfile, and it will work (remember that line from docs: "If the locals dictionary is omitted it defaults to the globals dictionary.").

But instead of using execfile, I'd recommend to import add from add.py and just call it in test. (That will also require to move call to add func in add.py to `if __name__ == '__main__':`, to not run add on imports.

Here some info on how globals and locals work http://www.diveintopython.net/html_processing/locals_and_globals.html .